# Why does the activation function come before convolution in DenseNet?

Tags: computer-vision

In the DenseNet paper, it says:

> each “conv” layer shown in the table corresponds the sequence BN-ReLU-Conv.

Why is it that the relu activation comes before the convolution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The paper talks about pre-activation Resnet-101. Pre-activation architecture is where they use BN- Relu- Conv. It has been shown to improve performance of Resnets in the paper Identity Mappings in Deep Residual Networks-https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.05027.pdf